# How to pass the location of file to Java code using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

The following is the JSP code.

How the code can be modified such that the location of the file that is selected using "Browse" option must be passed to a java program named new.java

Please advise.

```
<form action="abc.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 

        Upload File:
       <input name="file" type="file" id="file"><br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
       <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>   
 </form>
```

The html code above shows only the name of the file and not the location. And I dont even know how to pass the name of the file to java code itself.

Comment: See also [How to upload file in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `action` you must specify a servlet/jsp that handles the multipart request. It better be a Servlet (JSP is meant for presentation, not processing).

So, we have a Servlet (`public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet`), with a `doPost(request, response)` method. At that point you can use [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to handle the incoming file. [Here is](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) the user guide with a lot of code to just copy-paste.

[The servlet tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: am a beginner in Java... and not familiar with servlet and doPost methods. Kindly let me know any other way to solve the issue.

Comment: if you want to work with servlets and JSPs (they are two sides of the same coin) (and it seems you need to), you'd need to read about them. I updated my answer with the tutorial.