# How to pass the location of a file from JSP Form to Java Program

Tags: java, jsp

```
String fileToBeRead = "C:/Documents and Settings/Developer/Desktop/Anand exmps/Anand.xls";
```

I have completed a java program in which the location of a file is assigned to a string as above.

But what actually is required is, the end user should select the location of file in a JSP form that is developed using `<input type="file" name="file"/>` tag for file selection.

My query here is how can I make the location of the file that the user selects in the JSP form to be passed to the JAVA program that I have written already.

Gimme some ideas regarding the same. Thanks in advance. Since am a beginner in Java, elaborate answers will really help in my procedings.

Comment: It's a standalone Java program, not something running on your application server?

Comment: Yes its a standalone program. Not running on server

Comment: Duplicate of [To pass the path of the uploaded file to the Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653704/to-pass-the-path-of-the-uploaded-file-to-the-java-program) Answer is still: you can't. Read the answer and the links in the answer once again to understand why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input field's file type is not guaranteed to pass the entire path.  In fact, IE is the only browser that does.

The [file input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#file-select) is intended to upload the entire file to the server, not to give you the file's path.